# build an actionbar with a justified menu

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to make a menu to justify. the menu consists of 3 items as in the following photo

[image: each icon represents a menuItem]

here is the content of my file ***res/menu/menuab.xml***

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:title=""
    android:icon="@drawable/home"
    android:visible="true"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/quit"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title=""
    android:visible="true"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/logout"/>
```

and here is the java code

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
     actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.back);
```

Thk..

Comment: Just use `ImageButton`s or `ImageView`s in a `Toolbar`. Don't try to get a menu to do that. It'd be more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: I will try your method and show you the result

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to my problem, in the end I use a toolBar instead of an actionBa. For those it can help, here is the xml code of my toolbar

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="#ff6d7fe2"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logout" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Here is my java code

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Thank u @Mike M